# How to save a UUID in SwiftUI using @AppStorage

Tags: swiftui

When using

```swift
@AppStorage("navigationWaypointID") var navigationWaypointID: UUID?
```

I get a `No exact matches in call to initializer`.

I can work around by using a String and a custom property that uses the string as the source of truth but that isn't ideal. E.g.,

```swift
@AppStorage("selectedWaypointID") var selectedWaypointIDString: String?
var selectedWaypointID: UUID? {
    get { UUID(uuidString: selectedWaypointIDString ?? "") }
    set { selectedWaypointIDString = newValue?.uuidString }
}
```

Comment: Your workaround is the answer I also would have given. What's not good with it?

Comment: @ChrisR The work around means the app is wasting cycles converting to/from the string representation on each access rather than only when it needs to save the result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can confirm `UUID` to `RawRepresentable` protocol so it fits to one of `AppStorage` init.

Here is a possible approach. Tested with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2

```
extension UUID: RawRepresentable {
    public var rawValue: String {
        self.uuidString
    }

    public typealias RawValue = String

    public init?(rawValue: RawValue) {
        self.init(uuidString: rawValue)
    }
}
```

and then your original (below) code just works 'as-is'

```
@AppStorage("navigationWaypointID") var navigationWaypointID: UUID?
```

Comment: Perfect. Much appreciated @Asperi.